# Connection attempt failed in Python pydobc to SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server, connection, timeout, pyodbc

I have python code to upload a lot of data in CSV to SQL Server.  The code continues to fail for reasons I do not understand.  It's throwing error **pyodbc.OperationalError**.  I've got a temporary fix by restarting (manually) and looking for the last uploaded record and continue uploading from there, but that really sucks.

Here's the error message:

> ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider:
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\r\n
> (10060) (SQLExecDirectW); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10060)')

I tried setting the timeout variable in `connect()`

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server_name + '; \
    Database=' + db_name + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;DATABASE=', timeout=5, autocommit=True)
```

The thing is I don't understand the error. It's already made the connection.  It's made a lot of queries to upload data. But suddenly the connection drops?

How do I fix this?

Addendum:
I added code to catch the error, and retry the call to the stored procedure that is writing the data to the table.  I have it wait 30 seconds (I tried 5, 10, now up to 30) and then try to call the SQL again.  It continues to fail on the call to execute the sql:

```
return_key = cursor.execute(sql_str, values).fetchval()
```

I thought perhaps if I just waited and retried calling the stored procedure, it would work.  But no such luck.

Comment: Are you specifying `Database` 2 times in your connectionstring ? Once as `Database=' + db_name + '` and at the end of the connection string : `DATABASE=`

Comment: If it works for a while and then stops working... Connection Pooling? Does it work better if you use `pyodbc.pooling = false` before any other pyodbc functions?

Comment: I see that I do have a second database= statement.  I'll fix that.  As for the connection pooling, I'll try that. (Currently running some other tests.)